# Effect of removing a category from a categorical covariate

Tags: r, logistic, categorical-data

I have the following situation in hand:

- Binary dependent Variable
- 2 Covariates (X1, X2)
- X1 and X2 are categorical with 4 and 6 categories respectively.

I ask 500 people and then fit a logit model depending on the answers they give in the survey (answers to Y, X1 and X2).

Then I decide to remove category 4 of X1, so the covariate X1 has only 3.  categories now. Then I run a logit model the same way I did previously. What is the effect on the results of such a procedure? Are the parameter estimates comparable between regressions?

My concern is that by removing some categories that were chosen by people we may be biasing estimates as we omit information. In addition, Independence of Irrelevant Alternatives usually applies to the dependent variable, but does it apply to the covariates i.e. the choice between 
$X1 = c(red,black,green, yellow)$? So that black is independent from green, and if I remove a level I may bias results?

I coded in R a small chunk to investigate but I think it is not very reliable...

```
library("AlgDesign")
library("stats")
library("ade4")
rm(list = ls())
set.seed(10)
fact <- gen.factorial(c(4,6), nVars = 2, factors = "all")
Y <- sample(c(0,1),size = 24, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5,0.5))
fact.binary <- acm.disjonctif(fact)
dataXY <- cbind(Y,fact.binary)
model1 <- glm(data = dataXY, Y~.-1, family = binomial(link = "logit"))


#We remove category 4 of X1 
set.seed(10)
fact2 <- gen.factorial(c(3,6), nVars = 2, factors = "all") #notice it is 3 levels the first variable
Y2 <- sample(c(0,1),size = 18, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5,0.5))
fact.binary2 <- acm.disjonctif(fact2)
dataXY2 <- cbind(Y2,fact.binary2)
# dataXY2 <- dataXY[dataXY$X1.4==1,]

model2 <- glm(data = dataXY2, Y2~.-1, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

summary(model1)
summary(model2)
```

**So, some intuition on what the implications of estimating a model with categorical variables, removing a category of a covariate and then re-estimating it would be really useful for my research!** Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean to remove black from {red, black, green, yellow}? Are you not including those observations in the analysis? Are you saying that they were actually yellow? Something else?

Comment: I mean that I have answers on the four colors. Then I remove one, let's say black, and run the analysis with the very same observations except those that black color was chosen. @gung

Comment: So does that mean you have fewer observations in your second analysis?

Comment: @mdewey YES, there are few observations!

Comment: In that case i would have thought that the answer is probably: "In general everything changes in a way which is hard to predict".